# Boot failure on PowerPC Mac with encrypted LVM

Tags: boot-failure, encryption, powerpc

I have a PowerBook G4 that was previously running Debian squeeze, and before that, OS X Leopard. It worked fine under Debian, but I disliked the GUI, so I decided to give Ubuntu a try.

I downloaded a copy of the [PowerPC Desktop ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso), but the GUI was messed up: most of the screen was taken up by a large white rectangle, which was presumably supposed to be a window, but didn't load properly. Nothing happened when I clicked on the menus at the top, except for the one in the top-right corner that has shutdown options. I tried to restart it using that, but I didn't get a dialog or anything, so I finally ended up using control-command-power to force a reboot.

I then tried the [alternate ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc.iso) to see if I could just use the textual installer. That worked, and I don't remember having any problems with the login screen, but after that, I had the same problems as with the live disc. I had no problems using the tty's, though, which is mostly what I did under Debian.

I later found that if you want full-disk encryption, you must set it up at install time. So I rebooted to the alternate disc and wiped the entire hard disk again, choosing the `entire hard disk with encrypted LVM` option during partitioning. The installation completed successfully, but now when I try to boot, I get just a black screen after the `yaboot` menus, no password prompt or anything. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing `Linux nomodeset` rather than simply `Linux` at the `yaboot` prompt (or just pressing return, which in my case defaults to `Linux`) worked for me.

Thanks to L3top from Freenode/#ubuntu for suggesting `nomodeset`.

Comment: (The graphics were even worse, but at least the tty's work…besides, that's a different question.)