# PowerBook displays “Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!” and stops booting

Tags: boot-failure, powerpc

I have an old PowerBook G4 that worked ([more or less](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175142/boot-failure-on-powerpc-mac-with-encrypted-lvm)) fine with a previous installation of Ubuntu Desktop 12.04. A few days ago I decided to install Ubuntu Server instead, and got a copy of Ubuntu Server 12.10. The installation seemed to complete successfully, but now, whenever I try to boot the system, it simply halts at some point after I unlock the hard disk. There is a lot of text on the screen (which is normal for me during a boot, except now it's mostly errors and debug information), the last of which is this:

```
[   26.338228] Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
```

Pressing <kbd>control</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>power</kbd> to force a reboot yields exactly the same results.

[A search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+fixing+recursive+fault+but+reboot+is+needed) turned up many temporary solutions involving kernel parameters, but none of them have worked for me. I don't think I can remove the default set of parameters (which I think is `quiet splash`), but I can pass additional parameters on boot. I've tried booting on AC and battery power, as well as using these combinations of kernel parameters while on battery power:

```
acpi=enable pci=noacpi pci=assign-busse acpi=ht
acpi=off
nomodeset
nomodeset acpi=off
acpi=off nomodeset xforcevesa
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: This is by no means a solution, but a daily build of the previous version of Ubuntu—12.04 “Precise Pangolin”—installed and worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a 15" PowerBook G4 and I was able to install Lubuntu 12.10 from a USB stick when I entered these yaboot paramaters:

```
live snd-powermac.blacklist=yes video=raedonfb:1024x768-32
```

I found that stuff on the [PowerPCKnownIssues](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCKnownIssues#A12.10_Quantal_Quetzal) page at the Ubuntu site.

Comment: I don't have another PowerPC machine to test this on, and I'd rather not wipe the one that currently works. Sorry. :(